# In magento2 , how to show dynamically added customer attributes in customer grid?

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, adminhtml, customer-attribute

In magento2 , how to show dynamically added customer attributes in customer grid?
I have used this [extension](https://marketplace.magento.com/clarion-customer-attribute.html)

dynamic added customer attributes in backend 
[image]

Customer_gitd

[image]

Comment: Did you check in the columns section above grid?

Comment: i will check it